# I want to print sum of two numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is not working and I don`t know why. I want to make simple thing that input two numbers and prints the sum of them. 
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num1, num2, sum;
    num1 = window.prompt("Enter number one");
    num2 = window.prompt("Enter number two");
    sum = num1 + num2;
    window.alert(num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + sum);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Page91Ex6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var num1, num2, sum;
            num1 = window.prompt("Enter number one");
            num2 = window.prompt("Enter number two");
            sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            window.alert(num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + sum);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do I need to do that? And thank you very much!!

Comment: because `+` in javascript consider as concatination operator so we have to parse integer value & then do sum

Comment: @user3819756 asks a very good question, and that is the reason **code-only answers are disapproved of**. Please edit your answer and insert the explanation.

Comment: You should use `parseInt(num, 10)` always. Never forget the base.